# ¿Por que List <Long> contains me retorna false?

Tags: java

Al comprobar si mi lista que es retornada de una consulta de BD contiene un numero con `.contains()` me retorna false.

Return false:

```
System.out.println(listaBd);      // Output:[1, 2]
listaBd.contains(Long.valueOf(1)) // False
```

El problema no parece del código si no de la lista, ya que si la lista la creo yo a mano retorna true.

```
List <Long> listaLong = new ArrayList();
listaLong.add(1L);
listaLong.add(2L);
System.out.println(listaLong);      // Output:[1, 2]
listaLong.contains(Long.valueOf(1)) // True
```

La lista la consigo del siguiente modo:

```
List<Long> results = new ArrayList<Long>();
results = (List<Long>)QueryUtil.list(query, getDialect(), -1, -1); //Liferay
```

Y por lo que entiendo, si no da ninguna `exception` al castearla es por son `Longs` validos

---

La `query` es algo así muy simplificada (con muchas joins y wheres que voy a excluir):

```
select idIdioma
from mitable;
```

`idIdioma` es una `fk` de tipo `NUMBER(10,0)`

Comment: ¿QueryUtil.list devuelve una implementación de List que no sea ni LinkedList ni ArrayList? ¿Puede ser una implementación de lista que haga algo que altere contains de alguna forma?

Comment: @ordago Devuelve un `List` del paquete `java.util`, aquí se puede ver el metodo [.contains()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/List.html#contains(java.lang.Object)) y aquí la documentación de [QueryUtil](https://docs.liferay.com/portal/6.2/javadocs/com/liferay/portal/kernel/dao/orm/QueryUtil.html). Ya que uso `liferay 6.2` y no se si tendrá algo que ver. Así que en principio debería de ser igual que cualquier otro `List` de `java.util`

Comment: ¿Puedes poner el resultado de hacer esto? `Object obj = QueryUtil.list(query, getDialect(), -1, -1); System.out.println(obj.getClass().getName());` Si es un java.util.ArrayList o un java.util.LinkedList no te insisto mas :-P

Comment: Si te devuelve una implementación de lista que no sea del paquete java.util.*, prueba a ver esto: `List<Long> lista2 = new ArrayList<Long>((List<Long>)QueryUtil.list(query, getDialect(), -1, -1)); System.out.println(lista2.contains(Long.valueOf(1)));`

Comment: @ordago `java.util.ArrayList`. Aun así he probado el código que propones, pero sigue ocurriendo lo mismo. Ademas al hacer `List<Long> results = new ArrayList<Long>();
results = (List<Long>)QueryUtil.list(query, getDialect(), -1, -1);` ¿no debería de utilizar la implementación del `results`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

EDIT: Después de esta ida y venida de comentarios, la respuesta a la pregunta principal de por qué el método contains devuelve false es en definitiva, porque **la lista parece ser de Longs pero no contiene Longs, sino otro tipo numérico que ha resultado ser BigDecimal**.

Hemos visto que el método `list` de la clase `QueryUtil` de `LifeRay` devuelve en su especificación una `List<?>`, y en su implementación devuelve un `ArrayList<Object>`

Lo que está pasando aquí es que al hacer esto:

```
List<Long> results = (List<Long>) QueryUtil.list(query, getDialect(), -1, -1);
```

La lista de `Objects` se castea a una lista de `Longs`, pero realmente no contiene `Longs`, sino `BigDecimals`. Aquí el OP pregunta en el comentario por qué el compilador permite esto, lo vemos más abajo.

El caso es que tenemos una lista que contiene objetos que no son `Longs`, sino `BigDecimal`. Al hacer:

```
System.out.println(results);
```

Efectivamente, imprime `[1, 2]` que sería el resultado de ejecutar `toString()` a cada elemento de la lista. Nos va a pintar lo mismo si la lista fuera de `Integers`, de `Longs`, incluso de `Strings` que contengan un número con cadena. Aquí es donde está el engaño donde hemos picado, que hemos asumido que ese 1 y 2 eran `Longs` cuando podía ser otra cosa.

Finalmente, al hacer

```
results.contains(Long.valueOf(1));
```

Al comparar un objeto de tipo `BigDecimal`, con un objeto de tipo `Long`, devuelve `false` aunque tengan el mismo valor numérico.

Ahora, a la pregunta de por qué el compilador permite hacer ese casteo, es porque **una lista de `Object` es compatible con una lista de `Longs` a la hora de castear**. En este caso el compilador sabe que hay una lista de objetos y nosotros le "decimos" en este caso "mentimos" diciendo que es una lista de `Longs`. Esto en sí no es ilegal en Java, estamos casteando de una clase `List` a otra `List`. Ahora, cuando hacemos un cast, perdemos el derecho de que el compilador nos de error en tiempo de compilación si los tipos no se corresponden, y si se da este caso, nos damos de bruces con un error en runtime.

En este caso, ni siquiera te ha dado un error en runtime, porque el método `contains` acepta un `Object`. Si la interfaz `List` estuviese definida así:

```
public interface List<T> {
   // public boolean contains(Object input); --> Así está definido realmente
   public boolean contains(T input);
}
```

Sí que te fallaría en runtime, porque el método `contains` de tu lista de `Longs` se esperaría un objeto de tipo `Long` como parámetro, y estaría recibiendo un `BigDecimal`.

Fíjate también que el casteo de `List<Object>` a `List<Long>` es compatible, pero este código no compila:

```
    List<BigDecimal> listaBig = new ArrayList<BigDecimal>();
    List<Long> listaLong = (List<Long>) listaBig;
```

Finalmente, la solución al problema inicial es la siguiente como indica @David DPG:

> La solución pasó recorrer la lista cruda de Object, castear uno a uno
>   a Long con `((BigDecimal) results.get(i)).longValue()` y añadirlos a una
>   nueva lista, ya limpia y bien parametrizada.

---

Esto es lo primero que había escrito para que quede como referencia:

He mirado la docu de QueryUtil.list: https://github.com/liferay/liferay-portal/blob/master/portal-kernel/src/com/liferay/portal/kernel/dao/orm/QueryUtil.java (línea 87) y la lista que devuelve es un ArrayList de Objects.

Se me ocurre, que realmente la lista es una lista de `Integer` que tiene el 1 y el 2 como enteros, y luego el `contains` da false, ya que no coincide el `1` entero con el `1L`.

Pego un código donde ocurre esto:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    Object x = new ArrayList<Object>();
    ((List<Integer>) x).add(1);
    ((List<Integer>) x).add(2);
    List<Long> y = (List<Long>) x;
    System.out.println(y); // Escribe [1, 2]
    System.out.println(y.contains(Long.valueOf(1))); // Escribe false!
}
```

Comment: se agradece el aporte.. pero no es una respuesta esto.. no?

Comment: @gbianchi, no es respuesta pero no me cabe como comentario

Comment: ¿Si eso fuese así por que me obliga a castear el `int` a `Long` para hacer el contains? hasta donde entiendo, estoy casteando lo que me devuelve (el arraylist de Objects) a `List<Long>`

Comment: mejor borrala entonces, y si quieres pasate por el [chat] que ahi estamos hablando de esto.. el campo respuestas, es solo para respuestas...

Comment: En realidad tu respuesta va por el camino correcto (segun lo que estamos analizando).. me desdigo no borres nada!!!

Comment: Tu respuesta va por el buen camino, pero se queda corta. Es por eso, pero estaría bien que explicases por qué `contains` no da error en tiempo de compilación si los tipos son diferentes, y paso por paso qué es lo que ocurre

Comment: parece que tenias razón en este caso no era `Integer` pero si `BigDecimal` lo que me estaba retornando y no se por que no lo casteaba correctamente. Si puedes clarificar el porque de tu respuesta para dejarla perfect :). Y muchas gracias por la ayuda!

Comment: @x3k_js He editado la respuesta con los últimos descubrimientos

Comment: Una respuesta de las que te hacen sentir orgulloso de estar en SOes. Como pequeño apunte, la solución pasó recorrer la lista cruda de `Object`, castear uno a uno a `Long` con `((BigInteger)results.get(i)).longValue()` y añadirlos a una nueva lista, ya limpia y bien parametrizada.

Comment: @DavidDPG añadido a la respuesta y creo que con esto ya queda el caso resuelto ^_^U

Comment: la respuesta de por que los castea es un poco enredada pero es por que ambos heredan de java.lang.Number, como entrega una lista de objetos y heredan de Number, el compilador permite hacer el casteo, el problema de las listas de genéricos es que si no les especificas ciertas cosas el compilador no detecta bien el tipo, es el mismo problema si tratas de sobrescribir un método con un parámetro lista, por ejemplo tienes metodo(List<String>)  y otro metodo(List<Boolean>) el compilador no te va dejar por que supuestamente ya tienes una función con los mismo parámetros.

Answer (score 3):

Aunque ya habéis encontrado la causa, creo que es conveniente aclarar que: En tiempo de compilación, el compilador permite castear la *List* de *Object* a una *List* de *Long* porque son compatibles. Sin embargo, tras compilar, debido al **borrado de tipos** Java trabajará con *List* sin tipar; por lo que al añadir los valores a la lista no está "obligado" a utilizar el tipo Long. Por eso no da un error de ejecución cuando decide añadir la info recuperada de BBDD como BigDecimal.