# ¿Como almacenar diferentes tipos de objetos en un mismo contenedor/lista?

Tags: java

Tengo diferentes clases:

```
class Gato{...}
class Perro{...}
class Pulpo{...}
```

Me gustaría almacenar los diferentes objetos en un mismo contenedor o lista para mas tarde tratarlos:

```
Gato gato = new Gato("Garfield");
Perro perro = new Perro("Tobi");
Pulpo pulpo = new Pulpo("Paul");
```

Pero obviamente no lo puedo hacer en una lista `tipada`:

```
ArrayList <Gato> listaContenedor = new ArrayList<Gato>();
listaContenedor.add(gato);
listaContenedor.add(perro); //Perro cannot be converted to Gato
```

---

¿Como podría almacenarlos en un mismo contenedor/lista?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**No uses `Object` por defecto**.

Si tienes algún tipo base del cual éstos hereden, *especialmente si es una interfaz*, crea una lista con ese tipo base:

```
interface Animal {
}

class Perro implements Animal {
}

class Gato implements Animal {
}

class Pulpo implements Animal {
}
// y así con todas
```

Podrás hacer una lista con todas ellas y compartir comportamiento:

```
List<Animal> animales = new ArrayList<>();
animales.add(gato);
animales.add(perro);
animales.add(pulpo);
```

Y si quieres darles comportamiento común, añade el método a la interfaz:

```
interface Animal {
   public void hacerSonido();
}

class Perro implements Animal {

    @Overrride
    public void hacerSonido() {
        System.out.println("Guau");
    }
}

class Gato implements Animal {

    @Overrride
    public void hacerSonido() {
        System.out.println("Miau");
    }
}

class Pulpo implements Animal {

    @Overrride
    public void hacerSonido() {
        System.out.println("Glub glub");
    }
}
```

Y acceder a ese comportamiento desde tu lista:

```
animales.forEach(Animal::hacerSonido); // imprime Guau, Miau y Glub glub
```

Sinceramente, si utilizas Object como clase base para un contenedor, deberías revisar tu arquitectura de dominio porque es un indicador de que hay algo mal pensado por ahí.

Answer (score 3):

### `JSON`

Para usar los `JSON` necesitaras meterlo en las dependencias (los objetos `JSON` son muy comunes por lo que nunca están de mas en un proyecto) e importarlo en donde lo uses.

Los puedes almacenar en objetos `JSON`.
Con esto podrás crearte estructuras diferentes que te vendrán mejor en unos u otros casos.

`JSON` de `JSONs`

`JSONArray` de `JSONs`

...

En este ejemplo yo veo mas claro un `JSON` de `JSONs` en el que el `JSON` padre puede ser tratado como el contenedor y crearte un `JSON` por cada objeto así luego los puedes tratar como objetos diferentes.

```
JSONObject jsonContenedor = new JSONObject();

JSONObject jsonGato = new JSONObject();
JSONObject jsonPerro = new JSONObject();
JSONObject jsonPulpo = new JSONObject();

//Pones los atributos de cada objeto en el JSON
jsonGato.put("nombre", "Garfield");
...

//Almacenar los jsons en el contenedor
jsonContenedor.put("gato", jsonGato);
jsonContenedor.put("perro", jsonPerro);
jsonContenedor.put("pulpo", jsonPulpo);
```

Luego para recuperarlo:

```
JSONObject gato = jsonContenedor.getJSONObject("gato");
String nombreGato = gato.getString("nombre");
```

---

### `List <Object>`

Lo mas simple **pero no lo mas recomendado**. Puede dar problemas si desconoces el origen de los datos de la lista como se puede ver en este caso [¿Por que List  contains me retorna false?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/316439/por-que-list-long-contains-me-retorna-false). O si se pretende ampliar en un futuro la lógica de la lista y añadir otro tipo de objetos tendrías que cambiar todo el código de como trataste la lista.

Lo mas simple sería meterlos en un lista de `Objetos`:

```
ArrayList<Object> listaContenedor = new ArrayList<Object>();
listaContenedor.add(gato);
listaContenedor.add(perro);
listaContenedor.add(pulpo);
```

Y para recogerlos casteandolos a sus respectivos tipos:

```
Gato gato = (Gato)listaContenedor.get(0);
Perro perro = (Perro)listaContenedor.get(1);
Pulpo pulpo = (Pulpo)listaContenedor.get(2);
```

También puedes crear la lista sin "tipar":

```
ArrayList listaContenedor = new ArrayList();
```

Docu: [java.util.ArrayList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html)

Comment: Como un programador que ha tenido que lidiar con decenas de ifs e instanceof, no puedo dejar esta respuesta sin votar en negativo, lo siento. Es muy cómodo ahora, pero esto es como una avalancha: cuando tengas un error de tipo `ClassCastException` empezarás a añadir checks y acabarás con cientos de líneas para manejar una mísera lista.

Comment: @DavidDPG aunque tener una jerarquía de clases propias cuyo padre común es `Object` claramente es un error de diseño, no existe una relación de esto con el hecho de evitar las "decenas de ifs e instanceof" que vas a necesitar luego. Si cambias `Object` por `Animal` igualmente vas a tener que hacer en algún momento un `instanceof` para no tener problemas a la hora de hacer el downcast.

Comment: @E.Betanzos Discrepo. Si consigues aunar un comportamiento común para todos los tipos en una interfaz, sólamente tendrás que iterar tu lista y pedir ese comportamiento para cada elemento, sin tener que preguntar ni castear, y dejar que el polimorfismo haga su magia.

Comment: @DavidDPG tienes razón, pero eso es solo en caso de que quieras ejecutar algún método común. Si por el contrario necesitas ejecutar un método específico de una clase más espcífica necesitarás el casting.

Answer (score 1):

El clásico contenedor, que muchos frameworks denominan "contexto" es un `Map`.
En un `Map` podés guardar objetos bajo una clave de búsqueda o etiqueta. Por conveniencia, la etiqueta puede ser un `String`, entonces un `Map` definido como `Map<String, Object>` permite guardar cualquier objeto bajo un determinado string:

```
Map<String,Object> miContenedor = new HashMap<>();

miContenedor.put("mi-gato", new Gato("Gaturro"));
miContenedor.put("mi-perro", new Perro("Max"));
miContenedor.put("otro-perro", new Perro("Fido"));
```

luego, los podría recuperar a Max con `miContenedor.get("mi-perro")`.

Al igual que con otras colecciones, como el objeto a recuperar es un `Object` desde el punto de vista del `Map`, para poder recuperarlo como perro hay que castearlo.

```
Perro miPerro = (Perro) miContenedor.get("mi-perro")
```

`Map` también provee métodos para obtener:

- un `Set` de las entradas del mapa (`Set<Map.Entry<K,V>>`) que viene a ser una colección con los pares key (etiquetas), value (objeto almacenado) que hay dentro del map.
- un `Set` los keys (`Set<K>`) -etiquetas-
- una colección de los objetos almacenados (`Collection<V>`)

lo que permite iterar y trabajar con los valores almacenados de diferente forma según lo que se necesite hacer.

Y existen diferentes implementaciones de las que remarcaría para que investigues: `TreeMap`, `LinkedHashMap`, y `HashMap`.

[Acá está la documentación de la api](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html).