# Ordenar alfabeticamente los objetos comparando por atributo nombre

Tags: java

Tengo que ordenar una list por el atributo nombre de los objetos que contiene pero lo que he realizado me da error.
Este es mi metodo

```
public static List consultarPropietarios(ObjectContainer db) {
        Propietario propietario = new Propietario(null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        ObjectSet res = db.queryByExample(propietario);
        List<Propietario> a = res;
        Comparator<Propietario> compareByNom = (Propietario p1, Propietario p2) -> p1.getNombre().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getNombre());
        Collections.sort(a, compareByNom);
        return a;
    }
```

Este el error que da

```
 Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at java.util.AbstractList.set(AbstractList.java:132)
    at java.util.AbstractList$ListItr.set(AbstractList.java:426)
    at java.util.List.sort(List.java:482)
```

Comment: ¿Añadir un `order` a la query no sería una solución posible? Por otro lado, tu código es correcto, el metodo sort lanza esa excepción en el siguiente caso: _UnsupportedOperationException - if the specified list's list-iterator does not support the set operation._ [Collections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html)

Comment: Esta query no permite eso o no se implementarlo. Vale y como lo soluciono si el codigo es correcto que falla?

Comment: Perdón, con que el código es correcto me refería a que con una lista de propietarios normal tu código funciona. Por lo que deduzco que tu problema está aquí: `List<Propietario> a = res;`, prueba a castear los objetos de `res` a tu clase `Propietario` o itera en `res` para construir tus objetos `Propietario` y añadirlos a la lista.

Comment: segun el depurador no, eso lo pasa correctamente y el problema salta en Collections.sort(a, compareByNom);

Comment: He probado el casting tanto a List como ArrayList y sigue dando el mismo fallo

Comment: Supongo que el cast que has probado es `List<Propietario> a = (ArrayList<Propietario>)res;` o con `List`. De ser así prueba a iterar en `res` y te vas construyendo los objetos. `for(....){Propietario propietarioAux = new Propietario(/*Los datos de cada res*/);}`. [Posiblemente relacionado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/316439/por-que-list-long-contains-me-retorna-false)

Comment: Es mas he probado hacer directamente res<Propietario>= db. exampleQuery
y hcaer el comparator con res y tp funciona. El res esta correcto saca 2 obejtos el paso al List tb es correcto a obtiene los 2 objetos

Comment: Leete el caso que te he enlazado, creo que te sucede algo similar. Yo lo que haría sería iterar en el `ObjectSet` y castear cada uno a `Propietario` o mejor aun crear un `Propietario` nuevo y ponerle los atributos de ese `Item` del `ObjectSet` y crearte una `List` limpia en la que controlas que los elementos de ella son realmente `Propietario`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Si no me equivoco, estás usando ObjectSet, que  es una interfaz de la librería db4o (que está en desuso, no tiene soporte).

Dicha interfaz extiende a List, que tiene un método [`sort`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#sort(java.util.Comparator)). La especificación dice que este método lanzará una excepción `UnsupportedOperationException` en el caso de que no esté implementado (por ejemplo si la lista es inmutable).

Por otro lado tenemos el método [`Collections.sort​(List<T> list, Comparator<? super T> c)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Collections.html#sort(java.util.List,java.util.Comparator)), que permite ordenar listas sin usar el método sort de éstas. Pero tiene un requerimiento: para poder ordenar una lista necesita el método `List.set​(int index, E element)` para poder colocar cada elemento en su sitio. De nuevo, si la lista no tiene este método implementado porque es inmutable se lanzará una excepción `UnsupportedOperationException`.

Así que el problema que tienes es que la la clase que usa tu librería e implementa ObjectSet no es modificable.

Tienes dos soluciones sencillas:

- que los datos vengan ya ordenados por la query, añadiendo a la consulta un "`ORDER BY <campo> DESC|ASC`".
- copiar los datos en un ArrayList y ordenarlos:

```
ObjectSet<Propietario> res = db.queryByExample(propietario);
List<Propietario> resultado = new ArrayList<>(res);
Comparator<Propietario> compareByNom = (Propietario p1, Propietario p2) -> p1.getNombre().compareToIgnoreCase(p2.getNombre());
resultado.sort(compareByNom);
```

#### Nota final:

Hacer *casting* **no hace magia**: Le estás diciendo al compilador que cierta instancia es de la clase X, pero si no es realmente así, simplemente le estás engañando. No puedes crear una clase que implemente List y luego hacer un casting a ArrayList pensando que automáticamente tienes los métodos de ArrayList disponibles.

Es el equivalente a mentir en un CV: si por ejemplo dices que hablas chino, te creerán mientras no tengas que hablarlo, pero en el momento que alguien te pida que traduzcas algo, se descubrirá el pastel (*ClassCastException*, no es un *TraductorChinoEspañol*) ;)

Comment: uso lo que he encontrado en internet y viene en mi temario si esta en deshuso como se hace actualmente?

Comment: Si uso eso que me has peusto sigue dando error

Comment: ¿Qué error te da? Lo he escrito directamente, si ObjectSet no admite genéricos elimina esa parte

Comment: se habia rallado, funicona perfectamente gracias

Comment: Por curiosidad si la forma de hacer las query esta deprecated cual se usa actualmente?

Comment: Es la librería en sí lo que está en desuso. La forma de trabajar es correcta. En Java lo más usado es JPA, ya sea con Hibernate o con Spring

Comment: Si hibernate fue el tema pasado, Spring aun no lo he dado no se si cahera :P